# Early return a component inside a react functional component with hooks

Tags: reactjs

```
const LecturesExerciseItem = props => {
  const hasMultipleVideos = hasSectionMultipleVideos(props.sectionUUID)
  if (!hasMultipleVideos) return <SectionListItem {...props} />

  // multiple videos
  const [isAccordionOpen, setIsAccordionOpen] = useState(false)
  ....
  return <h1> multiple videos </h1>
}
```

*React Hook "useState" is called conditionally. React Hooks must be called in the exact same order in every component render.*

How can early return some component based on condition inside functional component with hooks?

Comment: Why not just move the hook above the if condition?

Comment: Have you try this: return ( hasMultipleVideos ? <Component1> :  DO your work)

Comment: @ZohaibIjaz for early return, I don't want to have if ( ) { ..... }

Comment: @HenokTesfaye Use kkesley's answer. It covers what do you want

Comment: @ZohaibIjaz yes, I'm trying to wrap the second condition in its own component.

Comment: @HenokTesfaye WHERE is 2nd condition?

Comment: @ZohaibIjaz if has multiple videos

Comment: That's the first condition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 options:

1. Put hooks on top of the component
2. Use a wrapper component e.g.

```
const LecturesExerciseItem = props => {
  const hasMultipleVideos = hasSectionMultipleVideos(props.sectionUUID)
  if (!hasMultipleVideos) return <SectionListItem {...props} />

  // multiple videos
  ....
  return <MultipleVideos {...props}/>
}

const MultipleVideos = props => {
  const [isAccordionOpen, setIsAccordionOpen] = useState(false)
  ....
  return <h1> multiple videos </h1>
}
```